# Symfony API platform DTO messenger input, custom end-point

Tags: php, symfony, dto

I have the following object:

```
{
    "exercise": "Chest Press Machine",
    "plan": 1,
    "targets": [
        {
            "weight": 10,
            "reps": 6
        },
        {
            "weight": "11",
            "reps": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I post that to my custom end-point, I want to create a DTO that it maps to, but I with also a DTO for each target, is this possible?

Here are my DTOs so far:

```
class Edit
{
    public ?int $id;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public ?string $exercise;
    
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    public int $plan;
    
    /**
     * @var Target[]
     */
    #[Assert\Type('array')]
    public array $targets;
}

class Target
{
    public ?int $weight;

    #[Assert\NotNull]
    public int $reps;
}
```

But I get a "No handler for message" message when I post to the end-point. It's the nested DTOs that is the problem, I have it working without that.

Comment: I have this working now, the code was pretty much right, however I get a 400 and not a 422 if their is something wrong in the Target i.e. the reps field is null. If there is something wrong in the Edit, it is a 422 as expected.